# Get most recently selected item (WinForms)

Tags: winforms, listbox

Scenario:

- Windows Form
- Listbox
- SelectionMode = MultiSimple
- Items 1 and 5 are selected already
- User selects item 3 by clicking on it or by pressing the spacebar after it has focus

**Q: How do I get its index or value on SelectionChanged? I.e., how do I know which item was just selected (or de-selected)? FYI, SelectedItem will return item 1 (i.e., the item at index 0 in the SelectedItems collection).**

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `SelectedItems`, it will tell you all of the items that are selected.

In terms of knowing with item was just selected, you might have to remember what the old `SelectedItems` are, and compare to the new `SelectedItems`.

You can also check the `EventArgs` of the `SelectionChanged` event, however, I don't think it gives you that information.